# Submit iOS app, xcode 3.2 vs 4.2

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

Have recently completed developed on an app. It started a few years ago. Had it on an older iOS version running Xcode 3.2.

Had to upgrade to Mavericks in order to try and submit to the app store (from application launcher).

Have now ended up with an Xcode 3.2 which cant get the simulator to work (asks for an SDK, have tried 3.2, 4.0, 4.1 and 4.2 but no joy). As well as an Xcode 5 which seems to require a lot of changes to my app in order to get it working.

For the Xcode 3.2 version I have done all provisional profile stuff and currently working on getting through the errors that application launcher throws at me.

2 questions.

1. Is it even possible to upload an app built on an older Xcode 3.2 (and presumably SDK)?
2. It is recommended I just move to Xcode 5 any put the hours in to get it working again on here?

Would really appreciate help.

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. No, it is not possible. Currently apps have to be built using the iOS6 SDK as a minimum, and in February 2014 this will change to the iOS7 SDK and Xcode 5.
2. Yes. If there are problems with your app then they need to be resolved before submission. A new app should be built using the latest tools. Particularly given the answer to 1, you will have to bite the bullet and make any changes that need making.

Comment: Do you know if its possible to get iOS6 SDK to work on Xcode 3.2? Am trying to find this out myself now.

Comment: @CraigTaub Almost sure it is not possible. Usually an iOS SDK is only compatible with the XCode version released along the SDK

Answer (score 2):

I've been down this path for 2.5 years now, migrating up the various versions of XCode, losing simulators for older versions each time (sadly).

But, the upload/keychain handling has gotten much better and the management of launch images, bundle info, etc. a lot easier as well.  Also, support for older versions of the OS is difficult with deprecated features.

So, in general, my advice, is that as time moves on, so should your tools.  Upgrade to XCode 5, bite the bullet, take the hit, and get your stuff out.

Answer (score 1):

Starting on February 2014, Apple will require all submitted apps to be iOS 7 compatible.
Just a tiny part of iOS users are still running iOS 4.x, so it's highly advised you'd update your app to be at least iOS 6 compatible (but since you're gonna have work to do, why not make it up to iOS 7 anyway?)

Answer (score 1):

On February 2014 iOS app will made the  minimum iOS 6 compatible.

Before this You can upload the app for ios 7 and your are making the app in  old Xcode as 4.2.

For making iOS 7  compatible if you will be add

App icon-60.png and icon-60@2x.png. in  your Xcode app

It will be work your old Xcode 4.2 and it will be become compatible of iOS 7 and iOS 6

Other wise you will be download new Xcode 5 to make app for iOS 7 compatible.